# How can i prevent duplicate Record in Array

Tags: angularjs

I need to prevent inserting duplicate Rec in `$scope.EmployeeList` Array   For that i wrote if `($scope.EmployeeList.indexOf(EmpDetails) == -1)`  but its not filtering my rec

```
 $scope.EmployeeList = [];
        var amtArray = [];
        $scope.G_Total = "Total Amount is";
        $scope.SaveDb = function (Isvalid) {
            var EmpDetails = {
                'EmpName': $scope.EmpName,
                'Email': $scope.Email,
                'Cost': $scope.cost

            }
            if ($scope.EmployeeList.indexOf(EmpDetails) == -1) {
                $scope.EmployeeList.push(EmpDetails);
                console.log($scope.EmployeeList);
            }
            else
                alert('Duplicate Value....');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use *indexOf* (it checks for strict equality), try *findIndex*:

```
if ($scope.EmployeeList.findIndex(function(e) { return e.EmpName === EmpDetails.EmpName; }) === -1) {
    $scope.EmployeeList.push(EmpDetails);
    console.log($scope.EmployeeList);
}
```

Comment: Thank soo much for ur Answer

Comment: but its not find casesensitive Like Abc  vs abc

Comment: That's not automatic, you have to turns name into lowercase: return e.EmpName.toLowerCase() === EmpDetails.EmpName.toLowerCase()

Comment: u mean  return e.EmpName.toLowerCase === EmpDetails.EmpName.toLowerCase;

Comment: yes, return e.EmpName.toLowerCase() === EmpDetails.EmpName.toLoweCase();

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Array.prototype.some` to find duplicate value.The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```
var empDetails = {name: 'abc', email: 'a@gmail.com'};

let duplicate = $scope.EmployeeList.some(function (emp) {
  return emp.name === empDetails.name && emp.email === empDetails.email;
});

if (!duplicate) {
   $scope.EmployeeList.push(EmpDetails);
}
else
   alert('Duplicate Value....');
```